# Crystal Reports with two different databases

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've made a report in Crystal Report that pulls data from two separate databases.  They are both on the same server.  When I try to run the report from my VB application, it says the table couldn't be found.  I'm pretty sure this error is coming from the second database, because if I remove one database from the report it works fine.

My question is, how do I get VB or Crystal to see the second database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than connecting to two databases, you can create dataset using two databases inside the application and apply dataset to crystal datasource.

For an Example:

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim obj As reports = New reports()
Dim crconnectioninfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
Dim crtablelogoninfos As TableLogOnInfos = New TableLogOnInfos()
Dim crtablelogoninfo As TableLogOnInfo = New TableLogOnInfo()
Dim CrTables As Tables
Try
    If _report = "ISR" Then
        crconnectioninfo.ServerName = AquaInvoice.Properties.Settings.[Default].dsn_name
        crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = AquaInvoice.Properties.Settings.[Default].databaseclient
        crconnectioninfo.UserID = AquaInvoice.Properties.Settings.[Default].db_user
        crconnectioninfo.Password = AquaInvoice.Properties.Settings.[Default].db_password

        'Set report path
        Dim AppPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\rptInvoiceSummary.rpt"
        'load report
        reportDocument1.Load(AppPath)

       'Retrieve data to Dataset from the database. Here you can access two databases and create one dataset in you Data Layer
        ds = obj.InvoiceSearchBox(dtpStart.Value.Date, dtpEnd.Value.Date)

        'Set report source
        reportDocument1.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        reportDocument1.Database.Tables(1).SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
        'Set parameter values
        reportDocument1.SetParameterValue("Start", dtpStart.Value.Date)
        reportDocument1.SetParameterValue("End", dtpEnd.Value.Date)
        'set viewer
        crvDateRangeReports.ReportSource = reportDocument1
        crvDateRangeReports.Refresh()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception("Report load faild!", ex)
End Try
End Sub
'This code originally c# and converted to vb using online code converter
```